# How do i make a bot status that shows all the members the bot is playing with?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently trying to make a status cycle command for my discord bot in discord python rewrite. I have made the status command but getting the status to show a number of all the users in all the servers that the bot is in does not work. When i try to print the code it works just fine. When i try to run it as a status i keeps showing playing with 0 members. I do not know how to fix this.

Code:

````
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import asyncio
import os
import random
from itertools import cycle

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '?')
status = cycle(["?help", "Welcoming People", f"Playing with {len(set(client.users))} users"])

@client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print ('Bot online')
    print (f"Playing with {len(client.users)} users")

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game(next(status)))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesnt work as expected is the following:

```
status = cycle(["?help", "Welcoming People", f"Playing with {len(set(client.users))} users"])
```

We initiate an cycle with an array that doesnt get updated. To explain lets type it out (the string we are interested in):

```
f"Playing with {len(set(client.users))} users"
```

At the moment of creating the string we input the values at that moment. This becomes:

```
"Playing with 0 users"
```

This will be used in the array cycle is holding. As cycle only knows this string it will only use this string.
If you want to update the string you have to manually change the string and update it each time we need it.

I suggest that you create your own variant of cycle. Which does update the strings. One way of doing this:

```
last_string = 0
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def change_status():
    # Update the member count string
    list[str_member_index] = f"Playing with {len(set(client.users))} users"
    status_str = list[last_string]

    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game(status_str))

    last_string += 1
    if last_string == len(list):
        last_string = 0
```

This code isnt complete as you still need to assign `str_member_index` for example. But it will loop through your statuses. And also update the member count status.